# Use of definite article, the, before "adjective"- "a million miles from its nearest neighbour"

Tags: articles, adjectives, definite-article, determiners

> In a scale model in which the stars are ships, the average ship will be over a million miles from its ***nearest*** neighbour.

Why the writer not use **THE** before the adjective ***nearest***?

Answer (score 1):

We use determiners before nouns, and determiners can be classified in five groups ([Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-the-my-some-this)):

- Articles: a/an, the
- Demonstratives: this, that, these, those
- Possessives: my, your, his, her, its, our, their, x’s (possessive ’s)
- Quantifiers: (a) few, fewer, (a) little, many, much, more, most, some, any, etc.
- Numbers: one, two, three, etc.

I the sentence you quoted, the author wants to describe the vicinity of a ship and they chose a possessive determiner. Although I don't know what the writer tries to convey by "the average ship", perhaps average in size, he or she could simply say:

> The distance between one (average?) ship to the other will be more than a million miles.

---

My side note: Personally, I haven't faced a sentence which had two determiners before a noun. So, apart from the fact that it could sound odd, I would think that is not grammatical to have two determiners in a row.However, I am not 100 percent sure myself.

Comment: You can have two determiners in a row in at least some cases, such as ["The Nine Billion Names of God"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God).  I feel like there are probably some rules about when you can and can't, but numbers are definitely one case where you can have.

Comment: @stangdon thanks for pointing it out. I will edit this answer to add more details on this.

Comment: In modern English, articles, demonstratives, and possessives are mutually exclusive: you cannot have two of them in the same noun phrase.